# When is a string built / created / compiled?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, sharedpreferences, companion-object

When will these string get their value and should they all produce the same value?

```
class StringFactory{
    companion object{
        val str1 = App.shared.userSettings.getString(key, "")

        val str2: String
        get(){
            return App.shared.userSettings.getString(key, "")
        }

        val str3 = getUserKey()
        fun getUserKey():String {
            return App.shared.userSettings.getString(key, "")
        }
    }
}
```

When will these change their value?
When the code compiles, when I read them or at some other time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str1` and `str3` properties are assigned on creation of `StringFactory.Companion` and never change their value.

In `str2` the property will get the value from `userSettings` anytime you access it. There's no field for storing that value. It basically behaves the same as `getUserKey()`.